# Installing Wine.hq in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wine

I'm not sure how to install Wine on my Linux laptop computer. I have went to the Wine HQ website and tried downloading it from there, but that failed. If anyone knows how to install Wine on Ubuntu 23.04, please answer.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details on what you tried but didn't work.
As an alternative, you can install Wine from the Ubuntu repos: `sudo apt install wine`

Comment: Similar questions re-appear regularly when the Wine HQ packages and instructions don't keep up with the current Ubuntu release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `sudo apt install wine`. It will install with out any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from the Ubuntu software center, or the software center of your distro. Don't try to install it from the website as it is more difficult to install it from there. You should also install the app Playonlinux from the software center in order to be able to install your Windows apps smoothly. You can search for the program you want to install in the Playonlinux app and it will show whether you can run it on your GNU Linux or not.